# How to change the URL from localhost to service iinside a pod in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

I have an application running on a pure docker environment. I wanted to deploy that in a k8s. Hence I created config maps, deployments etc. Below is the config file before deploying to k8s.

```
  config:
    message:
      - type: "fusion:expense:expense_type:v1"
        versions:
          - version: "v1"
            handler:
              request_uri: "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/expenses/"
          - version: "v2"
            handler:
              request_uri: "http://localhost:8082/api/v2/expenses/"
      - type: "card_type"
        versions:
          - version: "v1"
            handler:
              request_uri: "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/cardtype"
    ossprovider:
      endpoint: "http://localhost:19000"

adaptors:
  endpoint: http://localhost:8092/adaptors/
```

I created a service like

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fin-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8090
      targetPort: 8090 
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 8082
      targetPort: 8082 
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 19000
      targetPort: 19000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    fin-app
```

My deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fin
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    fin
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      fin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        fin
    spec:
    {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.containers.oss_messaginglayer.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.image.oss_messaginglayer.repository }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8090
              protocol: TCP
```

Since I created a service, I wanted to use this service end point in the config file as fin-service instead of localhost.

```
app:
  config:
    message:
      - type: "fusion:expense:expense_type:v1"
        versions:
          - version: "v1"
            handler:
              request_uri: "http://fin-service:8082/api/v1/expenses/"
          - version: "v2"
            handler:
              request_uri: "http://fin-service:8082/api/v2/expenses/"
      - type: "card_type"
        versions:
          - version: "v1"
            handler:
              request_uri: "http://fin-service:8082/api/v1/cardtype"
    ossprovider:
      endpoint: "http://fin-service:19000"

adaptors:
  endpoint: http://fin-service:8092/adaptors/
```

But I get connection refused errors at http://fin-service:19000. Where am I going off the track?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Service is being created in the `default` namespace, since you're not providing a `metadata.namespace` value explicitly. On the other hand, your deployment is specifying `metadata.namespace` to be `{{ .Values.namespace }}` (looks like you're using Helm).

You have a couple options:

1. Create your Service in the same namespace as your Deployment, `{{
   .Values.namespace }}`, in which case you can continue using
   `fin-service` to reference the service in your config, or
2. Update your config to reference
   `fin-service.default`, since `<service-name>.<namespace>` will also resolve to your service. You'll also need to make sure your Deployment is running in the `default` namespace or else your service pod selector won't find any of the deployment pods.

Check out the Kubernetes documentation on [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) for more on how services and pods can be accessed within a cluster.

Comment: Thank you @snormore. I realized the mistake that I did not specify the namespace for the service I am creating.